# Why are these lines being skipped? (java)

Tags: java, methods

Here's the relevant bit of the source code:

```
class Dice 
{ 
    String name ; 
    int x ; 
    int[] sum ;
```

...

```
public Dice (String name) 
{ 
    this.name = name ; 
    this.x = 0 ; 
    this.sum = new int[7] ; 
}
```

...

```
    public static void main (String[] arg) 
    {
        Dice a1 = new Dice ("a1") ; 
        printValues (a1) ; 
    }

    public static void printDice (Dice Dice) 
    { 
        System.out.println (Dice.name) ; 
        System.out.println ("value: "+Dice.x) ; 
        printValues (Dice) ; 
    } 

    public static void printValues (Dice Dice) 
    { 
        for (int i = 0; i<Dice.sum.length; i++) 
        System.out.println ("#of "+i+"'s: "+Dice.sum[i]) ; 
    } 

}
```

Here is the output:

```
#of 0's: 0
#of 1's: 0
#of 2's: 0
#of 3's: 0
#of 4's: 0
#of 5's: 0
#of 6's: 0
```

Why didn't these two lines execute inside `printDice`:

```
    System.out.println (Dice.name) ; 
    System.out.println ("value: "+Dice.x) ;
```

if they had then i would expect to see "a1" and "Value: 0" printed at the top of the rows of `#of`'s

Comment: A good strategy for this sort of thing is to step through the code from the start, and trace the code by hand, making sure to go where the code SAYS to go, and not where you are assuming the code says.

Comment: you shouldn't name variables like classes because `Dice.name` looks like you want to access the static field `name` of the class `Dice`, but actually you want to access the field from the object. See http://java.sun.com/docs/codeconv/html/CodeConventions.doc8.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`printDice()` is never called:

```
public static void main (String[] arg) 
{
    Dice a1 = new Dice ("a1") ; 
    printValues (a1) ; // You only call printValues
}
```

Answer (score 8):

Probably because none of the code you posted actually calls `printDice()`.

With the exception of the `main()` method, none of your methods in your classes are magically invoked - they need to be invoked by some other code.

Comment: wow. yah. that would do it. I miss things so badly soemtimes.

Answer (score 3):

You are calling printValues where you probably mean to call printDice.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not a Java master, but I think that you'd better avoid naming the parameters the same way as you name a class. When you write:

```
public static void printDice (Dice Dice) { /* ... */ }
```

you're walking on the thin ice, dude. Reading your code it's hard to know if you call the static methods or the instance ones. I have to admit that i was surprised that Java allows something like that as it seems to be very dangerous and hard to understand when reading. In a free time - while not coding - read some Uncle Bob's texts ;) Peace!